# What is an artifact in the context of a visual studio solution?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment, teamcity, artifact

Hopefully an easy question.

What is an artifact in the context of a visual studio solution?  What do they do?  What are some common deployment patterns?

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'in the context of a visual studio solution?'  Do you you have a good sense of build artifacts in general?

Comment: @JohnHoerr No I do not.  Although reading around gives the impression that it is less a Visual Studio concept and more of a build concept.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [docs](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Artifact):

> Build artifacts are files produced by a build and stored on the server. Typically these include distribution packages, WAR files, reports, log files, etc. When creating a build configuration you specify artifacts of your build at the General Settings page

And now to specifically answer your question.

> What is an artifact in the context of a visual studio solution?

Your solution is compiled by TeamCity using a [Build Step](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Configuring+Build+Steps).
Artifacts are the files you choose to 'keep' after compiling your Visual Studio sln file.

For example:

[image]

This assumes you have a sln that compiles 2 projects, `ConsoleApplication` and `WebApi` - this example says `keep all the output of ConsoleApplication and all the dll's of WebApi.`
These artifacts are held by TeamCity and can be downloaded as part of a deployment process.